# Looping different <div></div> in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to divs and I want to loop them. Example, I have to divs (`<div id="all">...</div>` and `<div id="slide">...</div>`). On page load, it will only show the div#all but after 30 seconds, it will hide div#all and will show div#slide and after 1 minute it will again show div#all and  this process will just loop through. how can i achieve this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/‎ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery functions 
     `$('.curr').hide(30000)` 
to hide after 30 sec and
     `$('.curr').show(30000)` 
to show hidden after 30 sec.